# dbplyr tbl and DBI dbListTables - conflicting results on table presence

Tags: r, dplyr, r-dbi

Here is my code

```
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), some_credentials)
dbListTables(con, table_name = "Table_A")
```

The above code returns `Table_A` indicating presence of table. Now I am trying to query `Table_A`

```
df <- as.data.frame(tbl(con, "Table_A"))
```

and get back:

```
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT *
FROM "Table_A" AS "zzz18"
WHERE (0 = 1)'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Table_A'.
```

so `dplyr` does not see it. How can I reconcile. I already double checked spelling.

Comment: Please show actual output of `dbListTables`. Possibly your table resides in a non-default schema.

Comment: @Parfait, it returns exactly `Table_A`

Comment: What happens if you run `df <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM Table_A")`?

Comment: @Parfait. Adding full path worked. Here is what worked `df <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM [DB_name].[Scheme_name].Table_A")`. It is still does not work with `tbl` command. Here is precisely what fails: 
`df <- as.data.frame(tbl(con, "[DB_name].[Scheme_name].Table_A"))`

Comment: So you do have a schema likely a non-default `dbo` one? You will have to specify that in `tbl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, any object (table, stored procedure, function, etc.) residing in a non-default schema  requires explicit reference to the schema. Default schemas include `dbo` in SQL Server and `public` in PostgreSQL. Therefore, as docs indicate, use `in_schema` in [dbdplyr](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/in_schema.html) and `Id` or `SQL` in [DBI](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/id):

```
# dbplyr VERSION
df <- tbl(con, in_schema("myschema", "Table_A"))


# DBI VERSION
t <- Id(schema = "myschema", table = "Table_A")
df <- dbReadTable(con, t)

df <- dbReadTable(con, SQL("myschema.Table_A"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a reproducible example it is kinda hard but I will try my best. I think you should add the `dbplyr` package which is often used for connecting to databases.

```
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), some_credentials)

df <- tbl(con, "Table_A") %>%
      collect() #will create a dataframe in R and use dplyr
```

Here are some additional resources:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html

Hope that can help!